# MAUI - Is it possible to enable biometric authentication if user hasn't enabled it in the phone?

Tags: .net, maui, android-biometric-prompt

I'm new to .Net mobile development. I've to add biometric authentication in my app. While researching, I found `plugin.fingerprint` Nuget packages which seems to authenticate the user with relevant biometric method from the phone.

However, I want to know if it is possible in MAUI to enable biometrics if the user hasn't set it up on his/her device? In other words, if biometrics are not enabled by the user in the phone (Android or iOS), can we trigger the biometrics enrollment process to enable it from our app?

Comment: No, the user has to enable it first

Comment: You should check https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric it uses the latest native APIs and is made for Maui specifically with good documentation and lightweight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because of the security measures in the operating systems and devices, the user will have to manually enable biometric verification on their device.

If they do not have this enabled, you will not be able to use it in your app.